# What does return do in this function

Tags: python-3.x

Shouldn't a return statement something I mean isn't returning something the reason return is here.

```
def countdown(x):
 if x == 0:
    print("Done!!")
    return
 else:
    print(x,"...")
    countdown(x-1)
    print('fooo')

countdown(10)
```

Comment: Return without an argument is equivalent to `return None`. It also ends the function (returns from it, to where it was called).

Comment: what if we didn't have the Return there

Comment: In this particular case, there is nothing else that comes after the if/else so without the return it wouldn't do anything different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns `None` and as a consequence just *exits*/*stops the execution* of the current function.

It is not mandatory for *return* to actually return something meaningful. In case of this specific code, it would work the same with or without the `return`.

Comment: what if we didn't have the return statement wouldn't it exit the function?